# Laravel Queue - How can I fire an event after a job is processed?

Tags: laravel, queue, pusher

I try to fire an event after a job is processed and push notification via Pusher. But It doesn't work, seem the event is fired but the notification doesn't not pusher when a job is processed. It wait for all jobs are processed and push all once time.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        var pusher = new Pusher(PUSHER_ID, {
            encrypted: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('test');

        channel.bind('App\\Events\\VideoHasProcessed', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })();
</script>
```

**Update:**

Dispatch a job

```
foreach ($request->input('files') as $file)
    {
        ...

        // Dispatch a job.
        $this->dispatch(new ProduceVideo($video));

        ....
    }
```

And my job class:

public function handle(ProductionRepository $production)
{
    ...

```
$production->render();

event(new VideoHasProcessed(basename($this->video->path)));

...
```

}

Comment: Can you show how you've set it up in Laravel?

Comment: I just updated :D. Thank you.